# How do I get the default color of Button text?

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, colors

I am designing a UI in SwiftUI. There are a few buttons that I have customised with a rounded rectangle. I want the color of that rectangle to be the same as the color of the text - blue by default, and light grey in disabled mode.

At present I am hardcoding the colors. Is there some variable or function available to match the system settings for either of those colors?

Comment: Do you have a code example of what you have tried so far? As of now, by best guess would be to use the the following modifier on the rounded rectangle: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25).fill(Color.blue) ----and change the color to whatever color you need it to be

Comment: I have taken what George said into account. So now the code looks like this: .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                            .stroke(disabled ? Color.gray.opacity(0.5) : Color.accentColor, lineWidth: 1))

Comment: What I want now is to replace Color.gray.opacity(0.5) with a call to the system like accentColor that would be correct for disabled text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default color of a button is `.accentColor`. This works for both light & dark mode too:

```
Color.accentColor
```

I can't seem to find out how to get the disabled button color yet, but I'll update this if I find out.

Comment: Thanks, I had just found it out. It seems to have an extension all to itself, whereas I was looking in the one that defines clear, black, white, gray, red etc.